# need static position

Tags: java, position, jframe

I have a frame with 25 JButtons each one with a icon. There is a method that changes the icon if in a position on a matrix there is a 1 but the real problem is with the sizes because 
the new icon could be bigger so the elements get "crazy" there is a layout or a method that keeps the position of the elements?

Comment: i use this.

if (p.matriz[0][0] == 1) {
                    //debo de cargar tesoro
                r = "/imagenes/t.jpg";
                url = this.getClass().getResource(r);
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                this.jbt_matriz[0][0].setIcon(icon);
                }
                else{
                
                
                }

and the new icon its bigger so the size of the Jbutton change and the buttons around it change the position.

Comment: A GridLayout should keep the JButtons consistent.  Why can't you make the icons the same size?